# Can you avoid the Boss in Munchkin Quest?

Tags: munchkin-quest

Are you able to use magic/tricks (e.g. a Teleport spell) to circumvent the final creature, and thus win the game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rules seem pretty clear on this:

> No card or power will let you bypass this combat!
>   The Boss ignores any rules, cards, or powers that
>   would take it out of the Entrance. It can never be
>   controlled and will never ignore a Level 10
>   munchkin for any reason, even if its card says it will.
>   *It always fights.*

You pretty much have to fight the boss... while teleporting him away would be the Munchkinly thing to do, you'll have to slug it out with the boss.